# Why is Spinoza still considered excommunicated (חרם)?

Tags: halacha-theory

In 2011, a member of the Amsterdam Portuguese-Jewish congregation asked for a reconsideration of the ban, with the hope that it would finally be lifted. (It seems to happen periodically that someone, somewhere, demands the ban to be revoked — the former Israeli Prime Minister David ben Gurion did so in 1953.). Apparently the request was denied.

I understand the debate between allowing non believes into a Minian is still indisputable, but surely there are no exaggerated steps to excommunicate (חרם) them by today’s standards.

I couldn’t find any arguments for why the request was denied, and so I am asking it here?

Comment: Can you provide an argument why it should be granted?

Comment: I recall vaguely that rabbi Herzog (2nd chief rabbi of Israel) has a teshuvah related to this. His conclusion being that the cherem was over once he died. If I can find it I’ll post as an answer.

Comment: @mroll that would be great

Comment: @Double AA My argument will be: We live in an age in which we don’t exaggerate to excommunicate  current Jews whom are non believersand preachers of Anti Judaism philosophy. Through them, including Spinoza many non believers (who were born this way), get to learn about Judaism

Comment: @IsaacBrenig That's a reason to not excommunicate current people. Doesn't seem too relevant to your question. The ban on Spinoza isn't harming anyone. Why touch it? You have provided no reason.

Comment: @Double AA But it is harming all the ones that are proud of their Judaism and would be proud including Spinoza as part of our Community, such as Ben Gurion and the many many others.

Comment: The ban doesn't prevent Ben Gurion for counting Spinoza in his community. He and you and anyone can count whoever you want in your community. But you can't pretend then that that community is a community of traditional Rabbinic Judaism (the religion). It's literally not, ban or no ban.

Comment: @Double AA no hybrid of Thor, Jesus or Buddha, discusses in heir philosophies Judaism, But many of Spinoza’s philosophies did discuss Judaism (even if contrary to the theology)

Comment: @IsaacBrenig Jesus did actually, and presumably that hybrid would therefore too.

Comment: @Double AA You got me there, so then the discussion only becomes in which Jewish community except the orthodox community is Spinoza accepted

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The request was denied because nothing has changed. The theological views espoused by Spinoza are still contrary to normative Judaism. The fact that his works are widely read and praised even among many Jews is a tribute to freedom of expression, but not a basis for rabbis to reverse their condemnation of them.

Comment: Is that the reason why they didn't want to lift the ban, or is it why you think it shouldn't be lifted? The question seems to be interested in the former.

Comment: "Rabbi Toledano went on: "The moment we rescind the cherem, even if we could, it would imply that we share his heretic views…" in https://www.thejc.com/judaism/features/why-baruch-spinoza-is-still-excommunicated-1.56419